# How to enable password prompt at Kubuntu system loading?

Tags: kubuntu, password

When I installed my Kubuntu I chose not to ask for a password at system load. Now I want to enable that option back, I want Kubuntu to prompt my password every system bootstrap. But I cannot find this option. Where this option is hidden in Kubuntu? (Or in Ubuntu, maybe they are similar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (Or in Ubuntu, maybe they are similar)

No they are not similar. Kubuntu is a derivative of Ubuntu that uses a completely different desktop environment than Ubuntu (vanilla). So the settings are different.

In KDE you have to goto **System Settings → Login Screen** and UN-tick the **"Enable Auto-Login"** box of your user(name).

See the following picture.

[image]

Comment: I just want to ask... what Colors theme are you using in this photograph? x)

Comment: @searchfgold6789 : The theme is a customized theme. It is oxygen, but I changed the colors...etc. Goto System Settings → Application Appearance → and change there anything you want.. Style, Colors..etc. Is commonly accepted that KDE is customizable..ad nauseam :-P

Comment: Yes, that works. I have a little different picture, I have only two tabs in **Login Screen**: **Theme** tab and **General** tab. And in **General** tab there is `Automatically log in` checkbox. I unchecked it. Thank you.